# Bash move files and rename it as username_filename in a different folder

Tags: bash, find, rename, mv

There are 4 user folders user1, user2, user3 and user4.

They all have music in their folder and I need to move these .mp4, .mkv and .mp3 files into the folder /tmp/Papierkorb

Also I need to rename it like, when user1 has a music file, it should change the name of the file into the name of the user_filename, from which user It comes from.

This is what I have now:

```
for file in $(find -type f -name *.mp3;find -type f -name *.mkv;find -type f -name *.mp4)
do
echo mv "$file" /tmp/Papierkorb$file;
done
```

This is what appears with echo:

```
root@ubuntu-VirtualBox:/home# bash script.sh 
mv ./user2/music/hits.mp3 /tmp/Papierkorb./user2/music/hits.mp3
mv ./user4/hits/music.mp3 /tmp/Papierkorb./user4/hits/music.mp3
mv ./user1/lied1.mp3 /tmp/Papierkorb./user1/lied1.mp3
mv ./user1/lied1.mkv /tmp/Papierkorb./user1/lied1.mkv
mv ./user1/lied12.mp4 /tmp/Papierkorb./user1/lied12.mp4
mv ./user1/1lied12.mp4 /tmp/Papierkorb./user1/1lied12.mp4
mv ./user3/test/meinealben/testlied.mp4 /tmp/Papierkorb./user3/test/meinealben/testlied.mp4
```

When I remove the echo, it says, that the folder after Papierkorb doesn't exist. I also don't know anything how I rename it into the name of the user, from which user the file comes from.

Comment: I assume that the error message is not `Papierkorb does not exist`, but  `Papierkorb. does not exist`, with a dot at the end of the folder name. This can be fixed by adding a slash as in: `/tmp/Papierkorb/$file`. As for renaming files with username in them, I would rather use a separate folder for each user.

Comment: @mouviciel I did that, but there is also a dot somehow ---

mv: cannot move './user2/music/hits.mp3' to '/tmp/Papierkorb/./user2/music/hits.mp3': No such file or directory

Comment: You have to create directories before moving files into them. Or you can move whole directories. More likely something in between: create user's directory, then move music and hits folders.

Comment: This is what I didn't wanted. I only need to move the files into that Papierkorb folder not their folders also. But I also realized later, that the folder got deleted while testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `find` you can group the `-name` predicates and use the `-exec ... {} +` construct:

```bash
for user in user1 user2 user3 user4
do
    find "./$user" '(' -name '*.[mM][pP][34]' -o -name '*.[mM][kK][vV]' ')' -exec sh -c '
        for file
        do
            mv "$file" "$0${file##*/}"
        done
    ' "/tmp/Papierkorb/${user}_" {} +
done
```

###### Notes:

- to make the code easier I used one `find` per username
- the `-exec sh -c '...' "/tmp/Papierkorb/${user}_" {} +` is a little hackish but thanks to that you'll directly have value of `/tmp/Papierkorb/${user}_` as `$0` in the inline script

Comment: find: paths must precede expression: `-'

There is this error. Also where did you write it, that it should look for the music files mp3, mkv and mp4? Or is this code at find only for the name of the user?

Comment: There was a typo `- o` => `-o`; you tested the code before my edit

Comment: I realised the typo ^^ And also I now understand that mM,pP part and so on. So my question in the comments got answered. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Using find and awk

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/path/to/users"
# for all users
find "$dir" -maxdepth 2 -regex '.*\.\([mM][pP][34]\|[mM][kK][vV]\)'| \
awk -F/ '{print |"mv "$0" /tmp/Papierkorb/"$(NF-1)"_"$NF}'

# for some users
# using multiple find folders
find "$dir"/user1 "$dir"/user2 "$dir"/user3 -maxdepth 2 -regex '.*\.\([mM][pP][34]\|[mM][kK][vV]\)'| \
awk -F/ '{print |"mv "$0" /tmp/Papierkorb/"$(NF-1)"_"$NF}'

# using awk user filter 
find "$dir" -maxdepth 2 -regex '.*\.\([mM][pP][34]\|[mM][kK][vV]\)'| \
awk -F/ '/user1|user2|user3/ {print |"mv "$0" /tmp/Papierkorb/"$(NF-1)"_"$NF}'

# using awk condition
find "$dir" -maxdepth 2 -regex '.*\.\([mM][pP][34]\|[mM][kK][vV]\)'| \
awk -F/ '{if($(NF-1)=="user1" || $(NF-1)=="user2" print |"mv "$0" /tmp/Papierkorb/"$(NF-1)"_"$NF}'
```

Using find and xargs

```
find "$dir"/user1 "$dir"/user2 -maxdepth 2 -regex '.*\.\([mM][pP][3-4]\|[mM][kK][vV]\)'| \
xargs -i sh -c 'mv "{}" /tmp/Papierkorb/$(basename $(dirname "{}"))_$(basename "{}")'
```